# Properly implement In-App Updates in App Center?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I am reading this documentation/article from Microsoft on how to Distribute Mobile apps with app center. The problem is I really don't understand how to implement this. I have a app on app center (Android) I want to implement mandatory update so that I can eliminate the bugs of the previous version. I tried to distribute the app with mandatory update enabled and it is not working. How can I fix this?

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/

Here is what I did I added this code on my **App.xaml.cs (XAMARIN FORMS PROJECT)**:

```
protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        AppCenter.Start("android={Secret Code};", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
        Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true);
        Distribute.SetEnabledAsync(true);

        Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable;
    }

    bool OnReleaseAvailable(ReleaseDetails releaseDetails)
    {
        string versionName = releaseDetails.ShortVersion;
        string versionCodeOrBuildNumber = releaseDetails.Version;
        string releaseNotes = releaseDetails.ReleaseNotes;
        Uri releaseNotesUrl = releaseDetails.ReleaseNotesUrl;

        var title = "Version " + versionName + " available!";
        Task answer;

        if (releaseDetails.MandatoryUpdate)
        {
            answer = Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, releaseNotes, "Download and Install");
        }
        else
        {
            answer = Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, releaseNotes, "Download and Install", "Ask Later");
        }
        answer.ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            if (releaseDetails.MandatoryUpdate || (task as Task<bool>).Result)
            {
                Distribute.NotifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.Update);
            }
            else
            {
                Distribute.NotifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.Postpone);
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

And here is what I added on my **MainActivity.cs(ANDROID PROJECT)**:

```
AppCenter.Start("{Secret Code}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
```

Comment: What is not working? What's the error message? Is the app freezing? What value of release details are you supposed to be getting and what values are you getting instead?

Comment: @Saamer I tried to release using mandatory updated and no dialog box is show that informs the user that they need to download and install the new version

Comment: any success on this?

Comment: @Saamer nope I created my own versioning tracker

Comment: Ok awesome! Yeah the AppCenter implementation is not a good solution for most applications

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this App Center documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin) for Xamarin Forms -

`You can customize the default update dialog's appearance by implementing the ReleaseAvailable callback. You need to register the callback before calling AppCenter.Start`

It looks like you need to swap your current ordering to get in-app updates working.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a lot of different reasons as to why they are not working. As you can see in the Notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/inappupdates) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin),

1. Did your testers download the app from the default browser?
2. Are cookies enabled for the browser in their settings?

Another important point you'll read in the links, is that the feature is only available for listed distribution group users. It is not for all your members. You could use a simple version checker for your purpose instead or you could use a [plugin](https://github.com/edsnider/latestversionplugin).